# Google IOT Core device authentication without jwt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt

I have an IOT device that is not able to generate JWT token. For authenticating with Google IOT core, we need to create jwt token with expiry time. Is there any way to create a static authentication, like username and password as fixed, as it is for local mqtt broker (mosquitto) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your only solution is to add a proxy IoT client that is able to generate JWTs.

Your devices will message the proxy using whatever mechanism and security you want and the proxy would manage JWTs when communicating with IoT core.

See [gateways](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways)